# Regular Language Problem?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

Let L be the set of all strings that are not in the English language. Is L regular?

From textbook, would like some help?

Someone recommended to me to think about how regular and regular languages are closed under complement. I am not sure what he means and how this helps me.

Also strings are a series of letters not broken up by spaces. So a string cannot be a sentence, it has to a be a group of letters. I hope this clarifies any confusion.

Comment: By strings do you mean words?

Comment: yes, strings also mean words

Comment: «Also»? I mean: do you mean strings are English words,as opposed to, for example, sentences?

Comment: Your textbook most probably explains that the complement of a regular language is regular somewhere.

Comment: strings are not sentences, they are any group of letters not broken up by a space. It can spell out a word or it can spell out something random. Does that clarify? I don;t want to say word because it does not necessarily have to be an actual word

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I see what you are getting at. The set of all grammatically correct English sentences would probably not be regular since it contains structures similar to matching parentheses.

Comment: Please add clarifications to the body of the question.

Comment: @Mark, I know. I am trying to get the question into one that can be answered :-/

Comment: I hope this is better.

Comment: can someone help me

Answer (score 2):

The set of strings in the English language is presumably finite. Why don't you create a DFA to recognize all of them and then negate the acceptance?

Alternatively, create the regex of all English words: (Aardvard | .... | zymurgy) and take its complement.

Comment: Why is it finite? You can make countably many sentences like «One plus one plus one plus one is five».

Comment: In fact, this website says that the number is bounded by 2 million. http://www.languagemonitor.com/number-of-words/number-of-words-in-the-english-language-1008879/

Comment: @Mariano: The OP has now made it clear that the strings in question are lexical items, not sentences. The English lexicon at any given point in time is finite, hence regular.